# How can we perform code generation based on KotlinDSL

Tags: kotlin, code-generation, kotlin-dsl

Is there a simple(or not so simple) way to generate code based on KotlinDSL. I am facing an application that needs to expose an API distributed over different nano services. I have a DSL describing the topilogy, but it is not open-api and it is not yaml. Is there an easy way to perform/implement code generation based on this DSL ?